# How should I specify command-line arguments for MongoDB?

Tags: command-line, configuration, services

MongoDB has instructed me to change its command-line arguments:

```
REST is not enabled.  use --rest to turn on.
```

but this is all I know how to do:

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

Where should I apply this configuration change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The various parameters that you wish to enable or disable can be set in the

`/etc/mongodb.conf`

config file.

All the command-line parameters can be mentioned in that file, and setting the values to true or false.

In your case, add a line as follows, preferably somewhere after the dbpath is mentioned.

`rest = true`

After each change to the configuration file, you need to restart the server to take effect:

`sudo service mongodb restart`

For more options, take a look at the [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/File+Based+Configuration).

Comment: I don't understand how this helps. Can you explain how to "use --rest" in this configuration file?

Comment: @aendruk I have added it to the answer.

Comment: So how do I set the `--config` flag so it will actually use this file?

Answer (score 1):

In order to turn on rest just type the following in your Terminal(Linux):

```
mongod --rest
```

Thats it.

If you want to allow other clients to use your **mongodb** via browser just type

`mongod --rest` (for to activate) `--ipv6` (to allow other users to access your server).